# Phonegap:After build transform and perspective CSS properties are not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I am making an app using JQuery mobile.

For swipe events i included one library.By using that i am able to use **swipeleft,swiperight,swipeup and swipedown** events.

I have tested my app in android **4.0,4.1,4.2 and chrome browser of android** 4.4.It works .

### CSS

```
#joy_div {
      perspective: 500px;
    }
    button {
      margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
    .left, .right, .down, .up, .reset {
      transition: transform 0.5s ease;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }
    .left {
      transform: rotateY(-40deg);
    }
    .right {
      transform: rotateY(40deg);
    }
    .up {
      transform: rotateX(-40deg);
    }
    .down {
      transform: rotateX(40deg);
    }
    .reset {
      transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
    }
```

### JQuery

```
    $("#joy_div").swipe ({
    swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
    {
    if (phase!="cancel" && phase!="end") {//start,move
      if( direction == 'left') {
        $(this).children('#joystick').removeAttr('class')
        .addClass('left1');
        moveClawLeft = 1;
    } else if (direction == 'right'){
                                                                             $(this).children('#joystick').removeAttr('class').addClass('right1');
    moveClawRight = 1;
    } else if (direction == 'up'){
      $(this).children('#joystick').removeAttr('class')
       .addClass('up');
       moveClawUp = 1;
    } else if (direction == 'down'){
       $(this).children('#joystick').removeAttr('class')
       .addClass('down');
        moveClawDown = 1;

      }
     }
    },
    threshold:10,
    maxTimeThreshold:5000,
    fingers:'all'
    });
```

Problem:

Now after building app ,It works fine in android versions less that 4.4 and in 4.4 these events are called but  transform and perspective css properties are not working.

This might be error in cordova wrapping.

Please help me to resolve that error.

Thanks

Comment: You're sure that the problem is that the properties transform and perspective are not working, and not that the selectors are not targeting the elements you want/expect? Like if you put `.right {color: red;}`, the style is in fact applied and the element text does in fact turn red?

Comment: PS - at first I was positive that #joy_div was a Joy Division joke :)