# Transform Property Unsupported by Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an Apache Cordova app with the Ionic framework, and building with Phonegap Build. On the main page of my app I have a couple rows of icons that look like this:

[image]

My problem is that on Android 4.4.x and below, the icons are displaced. I narrowed it down and realized that my `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` doesn't work on older devices. It seems like other people have the [same issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173258/phonegapafter-build-transform-and-perspective-css-properties-are-not-working)

How do I do this transform effect so that it is supported by all devices/webviews/browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with Cordova, but with the rendering engine of the webview. Try with a vendor prefixed version:

```
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be on the safe side use all the vendor prefixed version

```
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform:translate3d(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%);
```

Also use **translate3d** instead of **translate**. translate forces CPU to render css whereas translate3d uses your phone GPU making your transition/animation smoother